# GraphQL, Dataloader, [ORM or not], hasMany relationship understanding

Tags: orm, sequelize.js, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm using for the first time Facebook's dataloader (https://github.com/facebook/dataloader).

What I don't understand is how to use it when I have **1 to many relationships**.

Here it is a reproduction of my problem: https://enshrined-hydrant.glitch.me.

If you use this query in the Playground:

```
query {
  persons {
    name
    bestFriend {
      name
    }
    opponents {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

you get values.

But if you open the console log here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/enshrined-hydrant you can see these database calls I want to avoid:

[image]

My **Person type** is:

```
type Person {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  bestFriend: Person
  opponents: [Person]
}
```

I can use dataloader good for `bestFriend: Person` but I don't understand how to use it with `opponents: [Person]`.

As you can see the resolver has to return an *array of values*.

Have you any hint about this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create batched endpoints to work with dataloader - it can't do batching by itself.

For example, you probably want the following endpoints:

```
GET /persons - returns all people
POST /bestFriends, Array<personId>` - returns an array of best friends matchin the corresponding array of `personId`s
```

Then, your dataloaders can look like:

```
function batchedBestFriends(personIds) {
  return fetch('/bestFriends', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(personIds))
  }).then(response => response.json());
  // We assume above that the API returns a straight array of the data.
  // If the data was keyed, you could add another accessor such as
  // .then(data => data.bestFriends)
}

// The `keys` here will just be the accumulated list of `personId`s from the `load` call in the resolver
const bestFriendLoader = new DataLoader(keys => batchedBestFriends(keys));
```

Now, your resolver will look something like:

```
const PersonType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  ...
  bestFriend: {
    type: BestFriendType,
    resolve: (person, args, context) => {
      return bestFriendLoader.load(person.id);
    }
  }
});
```